# How do I know what function is being called when I use a string for the func argument of DataFrame.agg()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, suppose I have a DataFrame like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

and I call

```
df.agg(func='sum')
```

Is this referencing

1. [`numpy.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)
2. [`DataFrame.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)
3. [`Series.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)

I realize that under the hood these do the same thing, but I'd still like to know which function is being dispatched. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's internal details I don't think this would be documented.

pandas-dev handles those strings i.e `'sum'`, `'mean'` this way. They have a mapping where they map function to their internal cythonised implementation of that functions.

Taken from [`pandas/core/base.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L161)

```
_cython_table = {
        builtins.sum: "sum",
        builtins.max: "max",
        builtins.min: "min",
        np.all: "all",
        np.any: "any",
        np.sum: "sum",
        np.nansum: "sum",
        np.mean: "mean",
        np.nanmean: "mean",
        np.prod: "prod",
        np.nanprod: "prod",
        np.std: "std",
        np.nanstd: "std",
        np.var: "var",
        np.nanvar: "var",
        np.median: "median",
        np.nanmedian: "median",
        np.max: "max",
        np.nanmax: "max",
        np.min: "min",
        np.nanmin: "min",
        np.cumprod: "cumprod",
        np.nancumprod: "cumprod",
        np.cumsum: "cumsum",
        np.nancumsum: "cumsum",
    }
```

So, `Series.agg(sum)`, `Series.agg('sum')`, `Series.agg(np.sum)`, `Series.agg(np.nansum)` all call the same internal cythonized function.

Taken from [`pandas/core/base.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L331)

```
    def _get_cython_func(self, arg: Callable) -> Optional[str]:
        """
        if we define an internal function for this argument, return it
        """
        return self._cython_table.get(arg)
```

You can find how how they handle this in  [`pandas/core/aggregate.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/aggregation.py), They use `getattr` here, it seems like cythonized funcs are class attributes defined. I didnot find where but good place to start would be in [`pandas/core/generic.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.4/pandas/core/generic.py) take a look at [`stat_func`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L11455)

```
def aggregate(
    obj: AggObjType,
    arg: AggFuncType,
    *args,
    **kwargs,
):
    ...
    ...
    if callable(arg):
        f = obj._get_cython_func(arg)
        if f and not args and not kwargs:
            return getattr(obj, f)(), None
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: What's really interesting here is that, if `x` is a pandas Series, `np.sum(x)` does **not** use NumPy's implementation of `sum()`. Rather, it uses Pandas' implementation. If `x` has NaNs, `np.sum(x)` will ignore them which is not the case if `x` were a NumPy array. TIL

Comment: @Ben Yes, I made a PR about this 2 months earlier to mention this behavior in docs, merged with master but scheduled for `V1.2` tho. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35042

Answer (score 1):

@Ch3steR, thanks for helping me see the light. I want to elaborate on your answer an bit though..

The [source code for `aggregate()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/df32e83f36bf485be803be2b87d23135be30540a/pandas/core/base.py#L301) includes these relevant lines

```
def aggregate(
    obj: AggObjType,
    arg: AggFuncType,
    *args,
    **kwargs,
):

...

if isinstance(arg, str):
    return obj._try_aggregate_string_function(arg, *args, **kwargs), None
```

Then we track down [`_try_aggregate_string_function()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/df32e83f36bf485be803be2b87d23135be30540a/pandas/core/base.py#L301) ...

```
def _try_aggregate_string_function(self, arg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        if arg is a string, then try to operate on it:
        - try to find a function (or attribute) on ourselves
        - try to find a numpy function
        - raise
        """
        assert isinstance(arg, str)

        f = getattr(self, arg, None)
        if f is not None:
            if callable(f):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

            # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute
            # but don't let them think they can pass args to it
            assert len(args) == 0
            assert len([kwarg for kwarg in kwargs if kwarg not in ["axis"]]) == 0
            return f

        f = getattr(np, arg, None)
        if f is not None:
            if hasattr(self, "__array__"):
                # in particular exclude Window
                return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

        raise AttributeError(
            f"'{arg}' is not a valid function for '{type(self).__name__}' object"
        )
```

So, when you make a call like `df.agg('foo')`, **Pandas first looks for a DataFrame attribute named `foo`, and then looks for a NumPy function named `foo`** (assuming `foo` didn't exist as a DataFrame attribute).